# appending the results of my controller method to my select dropdown list MVC

Tags: jquery, select, view, controller, append

I have this code in my controller:

```
public ActionResult GetTimeOptions(string Date, int SiteID)
    {
        DateTime pickUpDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Date);
        Site site = SiteMgmt.GetSite(SiteID);
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTime endTime = DateTime.MinValue;

        switch (pickUpDate.DayOfWeek)
        {
            case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                startTime = site.OOSunStart;
                endTime = site.OOSunEnd;
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                startTime = site.OOMonStart;
                endTime = site.OOMonEnd;
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                startTime = site.OOTueStart;
                endTime = site.OOTueEnd;
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
                startTime = site.OOWedStart;
                endTime = site.OOWedEnd;
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
                startTime = site.OOThuStart;
                endTime = site.OOThuEnd;
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                startTime = site.OOFriStart;
                endTime = site.OOFriEnd;
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                startTime = site.OOSatStart;
                endTime = site.OOSatEnd;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if(startTime > endTime)
        {
            endTime = endTime.AddDays(1);
        }

        List<string> results = new List<string>();
        if (pickUpDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
        {
            if (startTime.TimeOfDay < DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay)
            {
                startTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(site.leadTime);
            }
        }

        DateTime tempTime = startTime;

        do
        {
            tempTime = tempTime.AddMinutes(15);
            results.Add(tempTime.TimeOfDay.ToString());
        }
        while (tempTime <= endTime);

        View().ViewData["availableTimes"] = results;


        return View();
    }
```

And this code works just the way I need it to. I need to append the results from

```
View().ViewData["availableTimes"] = results;
```

to my select list. Here is my select list:

```
$('#timepicker').append($('<option>',
      {
         value:  View().ViewData["availableTimes"] = results,
         text : results
       }));
  });
```

This code is not working however. How can I append the results from that controller? I know the controller method runs because I have stepped through it and seen the result generate the options I need. Any help is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use Razor sintax to fill drop down list with items.

1. Create combo box list with @Html
2. Bind data to combo box

Something like:

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItem, Model.ListOfItems, null, new { @class = "form-control1 col-sm-8"})

where ListOfItems should be loaded combo box values and binded to drop down list.

Comment: So I actually do not have a model. I only have the controller and my view. How can I achieve it without a model? @dkkd

Comment: You should create model with two fields: public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableDates{ get; set; } and
public Date SelectedDate { get; set; } and in controller fill model object with all available dates data and choose selected date which you want and when you call controller action and view renders it will automatically load all data to combo box and selected value will be selected inside combo box.

Comment: I do not have much experience with controllers and models. Could you write out an example of what you mean? Also, all the available date data is dynamic.

Comment: Also, is there no way to do it without a model?? I honestly did not want a model in this project.

Comment: the only thing is the result of the time is generated dynamically I can not do it with hard code. I am building an online ordering system. It pulls all dynamic data. pretty much nothing is hard coded that is data because it pulls all data for the store you can order online from. So even those time increments created in my method is doing is dynamically from selecting what day you want to order online and then it runs that method in my controller to figure out which day of week you picked and give you time based on the day picked and the store hours.

Comment: This is just example with hard-coded values, real world example would be to load data from database to list and show them in drop down. This is just example, once you get drop down loaded with hard-coded values you can remove them and load real data from database to list and fill drop down with real values.

Comment: I would recommend you to use models ... it's impossible to pass data between controller and view without models ... forget view bag and that things, you cannot use them for larger data sets ... model is just a class / object data representation which you want to pass from controller to view ... and it's very simple to use it, all you need is to know the concept of MVC ... you have actions in controller and they render view where you pass model which contains data to be passed between controller and view. You can include model on every view and use data inside view directly from model.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it like this:

1. Create model and call it DateViewModel.cs

   public class DateViewModel
   {
       public IEnumerable AllDates { get; set; }
       public String SelectedDate { get; set; }

   }
2. In your controller create this:

   public ActionResult GetTimeOptions()
       {
           DateViewModel dateModel = new DateViewModel();

   ```
       dateModel.AllDates = new[]
       {
           new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "2017-01-22" },
           new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "2017-01-23" },
           new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "2017-01-25"}
       };

       dateModel.SelectedDate = "2";

       return View(dateModel);
   }
   ```

We first create and load list with values and then put selected date to 2.

3. On your view put this:

   - on top of the page put this:

@using YourAppName.Models
@model DateViewModel

and create list with razor syntax: first parameter is selected item from model and second is list with all items binded to combo box control

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDate,  Model.AllDates)

4. Start your app and you should get combo box loaded with these 3 dates and selected one to be selected by default.